# How to replace a character by a newline in Vim

Tags: vim, replace, escaping, newline, vi

I'm trying to replace each `,` in the current file by a new line:

```
:%s/,/\n/g
```

But it inserts what looks like a `^@` instead of an actual newline. The file is not in DOS mode or anything.

What should I do?

If you are curious, like me, check the question *[Why is \r a newline for Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71417/why-is-r-a-newline-for-vim)* as well.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww this question is 10 years old... seems to be too old to migrate. There are lots of questions like this, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl/

Comment: @jww vim is a tool commonly used for programmers, and questions about tools commonly used for programmers are on topic in [so]. Although obviously this is more suitable on [vim.se].

Answer (score 3118, accepted):

### Use `\r` instead of `\n`.

Substituting by `\n` inserts a null character into the text. To get a newline, use `\r`. When *searching* for a newline, you’d still use `\n`, however. This asymmetry is due to the fact that `\n` and `\r` [do slightly different things](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace):

`\n` matches an end of line (newline), whereas `\r` matches a carriage return. On the other hand, in substitutions `\n` inserts a null character whereas `\r` inserts a newline (more precisely, it’s treated as the input <kbd>CR</kbd>). Here’s a small, non-interactive example to illustrate this, using the Vim command line feature (in other words, you can copy and paste the following into a terminal to run it). `xxd` shows a hexdump of the resulting file.

```
echo bar > test
(echo 'Before:'; xxd test) > output.txt
vim test '+s/b/\n/' '+s/a/\r/' +wq
(echo 'After:'; xxd test) >> output.txt
more output.txt
```

```
Before:
0000000: 6261 720a                                bar.
After:
0000000: 000a 720a                                ..r.
```

In other words, `\n` has inserted the byte 0x00 into the text; `\r` has inserted the byte 0x0a.

Comment: /r is treated as pressing the Enter/Return key. It works on all platforms.

Comment: for whatever reason, replacing all '\n with ',\n works when doing: %s/'\n/',\r/g

Comment: See also [Why is \r a newline for Vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71417/why-is-r-a-newline-for-vim).

Comment: I wish this worked for classic vi. On AIX v6.1, `\r` doesn't work like this. But you can press `Ctrl-V` `Enter` in place of typing `\r`, and it works.

Comment: Even this works
Type V followed by M holding control key which looks like this ^M which can be used instead of \r or \n

Comment: I'm late to the party.  If `\r` inserts `<CR>` and `\n` inserts a null, how would I replace something with a carriage return?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Ages ago when people were using teletypes, before computers, when you reach the end of the line it took the time of inserting two characters for the print head to reach from the far right to the left to begin a new line. So if any character came when the head was moving from right to left, it was lost. To solve this problem people inserted a Carriage Return (CR) and a Line Feed (LF). After  the speed of the printhead movement was reduced, different people took different routes- unix used LF, DOS used CR and LF, Apple used CR.

Comment: So, to maintain compatibility, DOS removes CR when the file is opened as ASCII, and has both when opened as binary. I'm not sure why this is a problem in unix, but this probably also has some quirks like that.

Comment: @Sunil I’m aware of the history of carriage return and line feed in different systems; however, it doesn’t explain the asymmetry between the meaning of `\r` and `\n` in searching and replacing.

Comment: It is interesting that to go back I would have to do: `%s/\n/,/g`, not `%s/\r/,/g`.

Comment: This answer has really come along way since the beginning https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71334/1

Comment: @SunnyRaj are you sure about the history of CR and LF? I was under impression that originally LF moved paper one row forward but did not move the printhead, and CR moved the printhead but did not move the paper. As a result, if your OS did not convert the input before printing, you could not just use just LF nor CR to get the correct output. MS DOS used raw printer data as the text file format, Mac OS used CR and converted from that to printer's raw format and UNIX used LF and converted from that to printer's raw format.

Comment: I had a long line containing a lot of explicit '\n' which I wanted to expand to a line each. after reading this thread, `%s/\\n/\r/g` did the trick! 
(notice the extra \, otherwise it searches for actual newlines)

Comment: Actually, I always do something like: `:%s/text/^M/g`, where I just press `^V` and Enter for the second part. Hope that help someone

Comment: @Chromium I'd always done it like that too, but I'm glad to learn this new way, which I think is better.  The advantage is it can be described in a recipe, which is more-or-less copy-pastable directly into vim, without having to explain the "where I just press `^V` and Enter for the second part" part.

Comment: So how do I match the null characters I just inserted so that I can replace them with \r?

Comment: @BenFarmer You can enter a null character in command mode by pressing Ctrl+V, `0`. So, to replace all null characters by newlines, type: Esc, `:`, `%`, `s`, Ctrl+V, `0`, `/`, `\ `, `r`, `/`, `g`

Comment: Please note: when they say hit control-v followed by the enter/return key, make sure you're not holding down the control key when you hit the enter/return key.

Comment: @0x0 The time to move the paper and return the head was in almost all printers much larger than a single extra character, so your explanation does not make any sense. Stuffing (often with NUL characters) is a common technique for slow devices such as terminals, but usually a lot more than one character time is needed and inserted.

Comment: But WHY is it like that?

Answer (score 241):

Here's the trick:

First, set your Vi(m) session to allow pattern matching with special characters (i.e.: newline). It's probably worth putting this line in your .vimrc or .exrc file:

```
:set magic
```

Next, do:

```
:s/,/,^M/g
```

To get the `^M` character, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Under Windows, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The only way I can remember these is by remembering how little sense they make:

> A: *What would be the worst control-character to use to represent a newline?*
>
> B: *Either `q` (because it usually means "Quit") or `v` because it would be so easy to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> by mistake and kill the editor.*
>
> A: *Make it so.*

Comment: I'm using GVim on Windows, and I need neither the `:set magic` (it's not in my ~/_vimrc either) or `ctrl-q`. Just a simple `ctrl-v` followed by enter creates the `^M` character for me just fine.

Comment: C-v doesn't represent a newline; it's the "escape next literal character" command.  I dunno what C-v is a mnemonic for either, but there's a reason it doesn't mentally map to newline.

Comment: Ctrl-v is a mnemonic for "verbatim" - i.e. escape next key pressed to its "verbatim" keycode/character. In Windows it's paste: to keep things familiar. Ctrl-Q is for "(un)Quote" maybe. Quite stupid, anyway - but you can use it in binary files - e.g. to search for Ctrl-A through Ctrl-Z (Ascii 1-26 I guess).

Comment: `Ctrl-C` doesn't actually kill the editor, although it can cancel you back to Normal mode. `Ctrl-V` means verbatim, and `Ctrl-Q` means that someone made the mistake of loading the `$VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim` configuration file. You don't need mswin. Just use your own vimrc instead.

Comment: wow----this is amazing. I used to do `sed -n l  ` till now. Good to know that the same can be achieved with `Ctrl-v` in vim.

Comment: This isn't working for me. When I hit Ctrl+V it pastes the contents of the clipboard. When use ":s/ /\r/g" I get an "r" character inserted. For \n instead of \r I get an "n" character.

Answer (score 123):

In the syntax `s/foo/bar`, `\r` and `\n` have different meanings, depending on context.

---

### Short:

For `foo`:

`\r` == "carriage return" (`CR` / `^M`)
`\n` == matches "line feed" (`LF`) on Linux/Mac, and `CRLF` on Windows

For `bar`:

`\r` == produces `LF` on Linux/Mac, `CRLF` on Windows
`\n` == "null byte" (`NUL` / `^@`)

When editing files in linux (i.e. on a webserver) that were initially created in a windows environment and uploaded (i.e. FTP/SFTP) - all the `^M`'s you see in vim, are the `CR`'s which linux does not translate as it uses only `LF`'s to depict a line break.

---

### Longer (with ASCII numbers):

`NUL` == 0x00 == 0 == <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>@</kbd> == `^@` shown in vim
`LF` == 0x0A == 10 == <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>
`CR` == 0x0D == 13 == <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> == `^M` shown in vim

Here is a list of the [ASCII control characters](http://www.cs.tut.fi/%7Ejkorpela/chars/c0.html). Insert them in Vim via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>---key---</kbd>.

In Bash or the other Unix/Linux shells, just type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>---key---</kbd>.

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> in Bash. It's the same as hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>, as the shell realizes what is meant, even though Linux systems use line feeds for line delimiting.

To insert literal's in bash, prepending them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> will also work.

Try in Bash:

```
echo ^[[33;1mcolored.^[[0mnot colored.
```

This uses [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). Insert the two `^[`'s via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

You might also try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which will give you this:

```
bash: $'\r': command not found
```

Remember the `\r` from above? :>

This [ASCII control characters](http://www.cs.tut.fi/%7Ejkorpela/chars/c0.html) list is different from a complete [ASCII symbol table](http://ascii-code.com/), in that the control characters, which are inserted into a console/pseudoterminal/Vim via the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key (haha), can be found there.

Whereas in C and most other languages, you usually use the octal codes to represent these 'characters'.

If you really want to know where all this comes from: *[The TTY demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)*. This is the best link you will come across about this topic, but beware: There be dragons.

---

*TL;DR*

Usually `foo` = `\n`, and `bar` = `\r`.

Comment: So I'm intrigued how you would substitute a character with a carriage return

Comment: @codeshot `:s/x/^M/g` should do. Insert the `^M` via `ctrl-v` followed by `ctrl-m`.

Comment: Thanks sjas,

You know this question is one of the weirdest of all time. 1008 votes for the answer which basically says nothing more than "vim does what you found. That's because vim does what you found. Never forget that vim does what you found."

I'd hoped to find a shortlist of codes for interesting characters in the pattern, the replacement and the reason for the weirdness so its easy to remember and predict other similar weirdness. That would have got my vote.

Comment: @codeshot a list of ascii control characters might help you. See http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/c0.html for further reference. I will update my answer to include two links.

Answer (score 65):

You need to use:

```
:%s/,/^M/g
```

To get the `^M` character, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I have to do <C-v><C-m> to get the ^M character.

Comment: This isn't working for me. When I hit Ctrl+V it pastes the contents of the clipboard.

Answer (score 46):

`\r` can do the work here for you.

Answer (score 25):

With Vim on Windows, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> in place of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

Answer (score 20):

This is the best answer for the way I think, but it would have been nicer in a table:

*[Why is \r a newline for Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71417/why-is-r-a-newline-for-vim/12389839#12389839)*

So, rewording:

You need to use `\r` to use a line feed (ASCII `0x0A`, the Unix newline) in a regex replacement, but that is peculiar to the replacement - you should normally continue to expect to use `\n` for line feed and `\r` for carriage return.

This is because Vim used `\n` in a replacement to mean the NIL character (ASCII `0x00`). You might have expected NIL to have been `\0` instead, freeing `\n` for its usual use for line feed, but `\0` already has a meaning in regex replacements, so it was shifted to `\n`. Hence then going further to also shift the newline from `\n` to `\r` (which in a regex pattern is the carriage return character, ASCII `0x0D`).

```
Character                | ASCII code | C representation | Regex match | Regex replacement
-------------------------+------------+------------------+-------------+------------------------
nil                      | 0x00       | \0               | \0          | \n
line feed (Unix newline) | 0x0a       | \n               | \n          | \r
carriage return          | 0x0d       | \r               | \r          | <unknown>
```

NB: `^M` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> on Linux) inserts a newline when used in a regex replacement rather than a carriage return as others have advised (I just tried it).

Also note that Vim will translate the line feed character when it saves to file based on its file format settings and that might confuse matters.

Answer (score 11):

From [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), the `^M` characters can be embedded in a line, and you want to convert them to newlines.

```
:s/\r/\r/g
```

Answer (score 9):

But if one has to substitute, then the following thing works:

```
:%s/\n/\r\|\-\r/g
```

In the above, every next line is substituted with next line, and then `|-` and again a new line. This is used in wiki tables.

If the text is as follows:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

It is changed to

```
line1
|-
line2
|-
line3
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's the answer that worked for me. From this guy:

----quoting *[Use the vi editor to insert a newline char in replace](http://jaysonlorenzen.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/use-vi-editor-to-insert-newline-char-in-replace/)*

---

Something else I have to do and cannot remember and then have to look up.

In vi, to insert a newline character in a search and replace, do the following:

```
:%s/look_for/replace_with^M/g
```

The command above would replace all instances of “look_for” with “replace_with\n” (with \n meaning newline).

To get the “^M”, enter the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, and then after that (release all keys) press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

---

Answer (score 5):

If you need to do it for a whole file, it was also suggested to me that you could try from the command line:

```
sed 's/\\n/\n/g' file > newfile
```

Comment: Note that this requires GNU sed.

Try `printf 'foo\\nbar\n' | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'` to see if it will work on your system.

(Credit to the good people of #bash on freenode for this suggestion.)

Comment: Yes, but the question was about Vim. There is Stack Overflow question *[How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999)*.

Answer (score 1):

in vim editor the following command successfully replaced \n with new line

```
:%s/\\n/\r/g
```