# Why is \r a newline for Vim?

Tags: vim

From question *[How to replace a character for a newline in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323/how-to-replace-a-character-for-a-newline-in-vim)*. You have to use \r when replacing text for a newline, like this

```
:%s/%/\r/g
```

But when replacing end of lines and newlines for a character, you can do it like:

```
:%s/\n/%/g
```

What section of the manual documents these behaviors, and what's the reasoning behind them?

Comment: What is the `%` for when searching and replacing?

Comment: @qed: by default `:s` will only apply the substitution to the current line. `:%s` makes it address the whole file. [More](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace).

Comment: +c24w I think he is referring to the '%' between the slashes, the first example the '%' being in the search location, and in the replace location in the second example, but @qed to answer your question, those '%'s are matched literally.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

From [vim docs on patterns](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Cr):

> `\r`  matches <CR>
>
> `\n`  matches an end-of-line - 
>     When matching in a string instead of
>   buffer text a literal newline
>     character is matched.

Comment: For me the point of confusion is that \r and \n mean different things when used is the search pattern and the replacement pattern.

Comment: @dlamblin Yup! See my answer :)

Comment: The question in the title is "why" and this is not answered

Answer (score 238):

From http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace :

> **When Searching**
>
> ...
>
> `\n` is newline, `\r` is `CR` (carriage return = `Ctrl-M` = `^M`)
>
> **When Replacing**
>
> ...
>
> `\r` is newline, `\n` is a null byte (`0x00`).

Comment: This answer helped me the most.  Also, for more information, `:h :s%`, especially the last paragraph. (via `:h :s`)

Comment: i wrote about that in even more depth - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18961239/805284

Comment: Yes, you wrote more, but I don't think you added anything material.

Comment: but WHY........

Comment: @IceFire Excellent question. I have no idea (even 13 years later). It's just one more "grey-beard" thing we have to memorize to make ourselves into the GNU/Linux sages we revere. :sigh:

Answer (score 143):

Another aspect to this is that `\0`, which is traditionally NULL, is taken in
`s//\0/` to mean "the whole matched pattern". (Which, by the way, is redundant with, and longer than, `&`).

- So you can't use `\0` to mean `NULL`, so you use `\n`
- So you can't use `\n` to mean `\n`, so you use `\r`.
- So you can't use `\r` to mean `\r`, but I don't know who would want to add that char on purpose.

—☈

Comment: Good point! So this is a hack around \0 - backreference to 0-th nested group - whole regexp. This is a very good answer, but it makes me dissapointed, that I can't use \r in replacement... (meaning: insert #(13), for example in a "normal" file (== unix EOLs).

Comment: OK, the answer is in the Vim docs. Just escape \^M or \<CR>, with a normal backslash. Nice. -----
       <CR>        split line in two at this point
                  (Type the <CR> as CTRL-V <Enter>)                  *s<CR>*
      \r          idem             --------                                  *s/\r*
      \<CR>       insert a carriage-return (CTRL-M)
                  (Type the <CR> as CTRL-V <Enter>)                  *s/\<CR>*

Comment: "Another aspect"? You're too modest! Explaining precisely_why_ this happens makes for a superior answer to all the ones just saying _how_ to work around it. +1

Comment: This is honestly *really* great insight into why `\n` has different meanings in search and replace patterns. Fantastic answer.

Answer (score 51):

#### [`:help NL-used-for-Nul`](http://vimdoc.sf.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#NL-used-for-Nul)

> #### Technical detail:
>
> `<Nul>` characters in the file are stored as `<NL>` in memory. In the display
>   they are shown as "`^@`".  The translation is done when reading and writing
>   files.  To match a `<Nul>` with a search pattern you can just enter [CTRL-@](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-@) or
>   "[CTRL-V](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-V) 000".  This is probably just what you expect.  Internally the
>   character is replaced with a `<NL>` in the search pattern.  What is unusual is
>   that typing [CTRL-V](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-V) [CTRL-J](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-J) also inserts a `<NL>`, thus also searches for a `<Nul>`
>   in the file.  {Vi cannot handle `<Nul>` characters in the file at all}

---

Answer (score 12):

First of all, open [`:h :s`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:s) to see the section "4.2 Substitute" of documentation on "Change". Here's what the command accepts:

```
:[range]s[ubstitute]/{pattern}/{string}/[flags] [count]
```

Notice the description about `pattern` and `string`

> For the `{pattern}` see [`|pattern|`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#pattern). 
>   `{string}` can be a literal string, or something 
>   special; see [`|sub-replace-special|`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#sub-replace-special).

So now you know that the search pattern and replacement patterns follow different rules.
If you follow the link to `|pattern|`, it takes you to the section that explains the whole regexp patterns used in Vim.

Meanwhile, `|sub-replace-special|` takes you to the subsection of "4.2 Substitute", which contains the patterns for substitution, among which is `\r` for line break/split.

(The shortcut to this part of manual is [`:h :s%`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:s%25))