# Replacing carriage return ^M with Enter

Tags: vim

I know how to remove `^M` in my files (`%s/^M//g`), but this one is just one line I'd like to replace `^M` with enter... what's the enter character in VIM (to use in commnad-line mode).

Comment: The general "replace by newline" question can be found at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323/how-to-replace-a-character-for-a-newline-in-vim But since finding carriage return is a bit special because of `set ff`, and this is the first Google hit, maybe we should keep this separate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can replace one character using `r<CR>` in normal mode.
Or you can enter a "return" in command line mode by typing `<C-v><CR>`.

Answer (score 66):

To replace carriage return character (which is `<C-m>`) with line feed character (which is unix line break character) you should run a bit strange command:

```
%s/\r/\r/g
```

It looks like if it is doing nothing, but in regular expressions and double-quoted strings carriage returns are represented using `\r` and line feeds with `\n`, while in the replacement part of :s command and substitute() function they mean the opposite.

Note that in terminal Enter produces `<C-m>`, so your initial request is not valid.

Comment: great; I read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71417/why-is-r-a-newline-for-vim) to better understand `\n` and `\r` when searching and replacing with vim

Comment: if you are running this in vim script then it is `exec "%s/\r/\r/g"`

Answer (score 56):

`:%s/\r//g` only works when:

- `set ff=unix`, which when done, automatically converts all `CRLF` to `LF`
- `set ff=dos` *and* `CR` is a rogue char that is *not* preceded by LF, e.g., inserted with `C-V C-M`.

  CR in LF CR pairs will *not* be found.

Therefore, if all you want is to convert every `LF CR` to `LF`, you should use:

```
:set ff=unix
:w
```

Answer (score 14):

In vim session try:

```
:%s/^M//g
```

Where `^M` is achieved by `ctrl+V+M` keystrokes together.

Comment: Technically it is two separate keystrokes. Anything after a `<C-v>` will be inserted literally.

Comment: Thanks, but I knew how to do that, for one odd reason this file only includes `^M` no return after that, so I had to do `:%s/^M/^M/g` where the last `^M` is the actual return.

Answer (score 10):

Similar to @ZyX and @anubhava, but assuming you're simply trying to remove the pesky carriage returns from a windows file, the following will suffice:

```
:%s/\r//g
```

Answer (score 1):

LF: Line Feed

CRLF: Carriage Return and Line Feed

^M : What vim interpretes Carriage Return part as. You can also search it with \r

For my case I wanted not to replace it with any other format of line break (LF or etc.) but just period and whitespace (. ). Because what supposed to be was a new sentence but somehow carriage return involved in. Probably user typo.

From

```
I'll be there^M
We can talk.
```

To

```
I'll be there. We can talk.
```

What helped me is:

```
:%s/^M\n/\.
```

or

```
:%s/\r\n/\.
```

(there's a whitespace in the end)

Both worked fine for me. \r\n easier to type.

Ctrl+M , Ctrl+V to insert ^M

(CentOS Linux 7.2)