# Open vim file with automatic replacement of ^M

Tags: vim, terminal, neovim

I want to be able to open a file using vim but immediately have it execute this command `%s/^M/\r/g`

I am trying to do this with the:

`nvim path/to/file -c "%s/^M/\r/g"`

nvim says that the pattern `^M` is not found but they are in the file. How can I pass the correct character in the command line?

I realise that `c-vM` works if you are in vim but I am trying to replicate the `c-vM` character in the terminal.

Comment: Ciro Santilli 刘晓波死 六's answer to this question should be sufficient for what your are trying to do, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939142/replacing-carriage-return-m-with-enter.

Comment: I will just run `dos2unix file.txt`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing carriage return ^M with Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939142/replacing-carriage-return-m-with-enter)

Comment: In order to insert ^M you must press Ctrl-v <Enter> probably you are inserting two characters instead one. You should also make nvim suppress possible error messages appending `e` at the command

`nvim path/to/file -c "%s/^M/\r/ge"`

Answer (score 2):

```
nvim path/to/file -c "set fileformat=unix"
```

As quoted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26903948/2544873