# In Vim how do I split a long string into multiple lines by a character?

Tags: vim

I have this long regex string

```
(\.#.+|__init__\.py.*|\.wav|\.mp3|\.mo|\.DS_Store|\.\.svn|\.png|\.PNG|\.jpe?g|\.gif|\.elc|\.rbc|\.pyc|\.swp|\.psd|\.ai|\.pdf|\.mov|\.aep|\.dmg|\.zip|\.gz|\.so|\.shx|\.shp|\.wmf|\.JPG|\.jpg.mno|\.bmp|\.ico|\.exe|\.avi|\.docx?|\.xlsx?|\.pptx?|\.upart)$
```

and I would like to split it by `|` and have each component on a new line.

So something like this in the final form

```
(\.#.+|
__init__\.py.*|
\.wav|
\.mp3|
\.mo|
\.DS_Store|
... etc
```

I know I can probably do this as a macro, but I figured someone smarter can find a faster/easier way.

Any tips and helps are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: select the line and `'<,'>s/|/|\r/g`?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you can add a newline with `\r`.

Comment: Related answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17667032/778118)...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace a character for a newline in Vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323/how-to-replace-a-character-for-a-newline-in-vim)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
:s/|/|\r/g
```

The above will work on the current line.

To perform the substitution on the entire file, add a `%` before the s:

```
:%s/|/|\r/g
```

Breakdown:

```
:    - enter command-line mode
%    - operate on entire file
s    - substitute
/    - separator used for substitute commands (doesn't have to be a /)
|    - the pattern you want to replace
/    - another separator (has to be the same as the first one)
|\r  - what we want to replace the substitution pattern with
/    - another separator
g    - perform the substitution multiple times per line
```

Comment: Mine too; no explanation… `:\`

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - Maybe our answers were _too_ effective... I already upvoted yours :-)

Answer (score 21):

Replace each instance of `|` with itself and a newline (`\r`):

```
:s/|/|\r/g
```

(ensure your cursor is on the line in question before executing)

Comment: Nothing to do with the original question or the answer, but Why is it `\r` instead of `\n`?

Comment: @Aperçu I haven't researched why, but in VIM you must use ``\r``as the replacement character, and it will do the right thing for the underlying OS. If you use ``\n`` as the replacement, the result won't be what one would expect.

Comment: @Apalala It was an answer to your question, not a question ;)

Comment: @Apalala See [Why is `\r` a newline for Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71417/211563)

Comment: @Aperçu Nice. Your 8.5k allow you to edit the answer, I think ;-)

Comment: @Apalala No it's a comment I can't, but sorry for the misunderstanding :) I think Andrew didn't saw my comment as well haha

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split a line by comma, try pressing this sequence (note: if you see `<C-v>` it means Ctrl-v, if you see `<Enter>` it means Enter); all other characters should be treated literally:

```
:s/,/<C-v><Enter>/g
```

`<C-v>` allows you to input control characters (or invisible characters) such as Esc, Enter, Tab, etc.

Type `:help ins-special-keys` for more info.

Demo: https://asciinema.org/a/567645

Answer (score -3):

actually you dont have to add `|`before the patter, try this `s/,/,\r/g` it will replace comma with comma following a line break.