# why does vim has different escape character for newline between searching and replacing

Tags: vim

**When searching:**

```
\n is newline, \r is CR (carriage return = Ctrl-M = ^M)
```

**When replacing:**

```
\r is newline, \n is a null byte (0x00).
```

Why designed in such inconsistent way?

Comment: @FDinoff hello, I want to know the reason of inconsistent, either of \n or \r is completely ok for me, what I care about is the inconsistent.

Comment: From the duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/71531/1890567

Comment: @FDinoff Ya, what's wrong if everything when replacing is the same just as when searching.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12389839/1890567. Vim was designed to be as backwards compatible as possible with vi. If there are inconsistencies it is almost always that.