# Swapping words with pure Regex

Tags: regex, vim, vi

I'd like to swap two words using capture groups in Vim using only one line of regex, but I cannot find a solution to this
for example

```
word1
word2

expecting:
word2
word1

get:
word1
word2
```

I've also tried `s/(word1)(word2)/\2\1/g`
but they don't swap their position or even replace

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: `vi` should support [`\_` to match whitespace including newlines](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/13603), but it doesn't want to work on my `vim`. Perhaps try [vi.se] for a better answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not matching the newline in between, and the newline is also not present in the replacement.

For the capture groups you can escape the parenthesis:

```
\(word1\)\n\(word2\)/\2\r\1/
```

Output

```
word2
word1
```

If you want to replace all occurrences and not have to escape the parenthesis you can use the very magic mode using `\v` and use `%s`

```
%s/\v(word1)\n(word2)/\2\r\1/g
```

---

If the word can be spread, you can match any character non greedy in between and also use a capture group for that in the replacement.

```
%s/\v(word1)(\_.{-})(word2)/\3\2\1/g
```

See [this page](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html) for extensive documentation.

Comment: @CarySwoveland No I read on this page that it should be a `\r`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71417/why-is-r-a-newline-for-vim

Comment: thanks for the answer, however if my words are spread in different places, this method will not work

Comment: @DarrenWang Then you can use 3 capture groups and match as least as possible chars between the matches and also capture that in a group for the replacement `%s/\(word1\)\(\_.\{-}\)\(word2\)/\3\2\1/g`

Answer (score 0):

I am all for designing under hard constraints but pragmatism has value, too. What good is it to wait for someone else to write you a super fancy one-liner when you can write three super simple commands on the spot?

```
:%s/word1/§§§§/g
:%s/word2/word1/g
:%s/§§§§/word2/g
```

If you really dig the mystique of one-liners:

```
:%s/word1/§§§§/g|%s/word2/word1/g|%s/§§§§/word2/g
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this exactly what you looking for, however Tim Pope's [Abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) provides the `:Subvert`/`:S` command which can make swapping easy

```
:%S/{foo,bar}/{bar,foo}/gw
```

This will swap the following:

```
foo -> bar
bar -> foo
```

`:Subvert` takes similar flags to `:s`. I am using `w` for word-wise and `g` for global