# How to replace searched lines with yanked line in vim?

Tags: vim

If I have a file:

```
aaa / new replacement line
AAA / old target line
random line
random line 
BBB / old target line
CCC / old target line
```

In this example there are 4 replacements, so the final file should end up like:

```
aaa / new replacement line
aaa / new replacement line
random line
random line 
aaa / new replacement line
aaa / new replacement line
```

I have an attempt at an answer below but would like to see your input on this also.
Maybe there is a more successful 'vim golf' approach I am unaware of. Maybe I'm just being really dumb and there is a simple command for this.

Basically, the question is this: if I have a line yanked into a register, how do I completely replace searched lines matching 'old target line'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use <kbd>0y$</kbd> to yank your replacement line - this won't include the newline.

Then use:

```
%s/.*old target line.*/\=@"
```

To replace the target lines with the contents of the `unnamed` register, which will contain the last yank.

Comment: Sweet, that's way more efficient than before!

Answer (score 0):

I first grab the 'aaa / new replacement line' by using `"aY`, save into register a

Then I remove the carriage return using the following, from [remove newlines from a register in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228079/remove-newlines-from-a-register-in-vim):

```
:let @a=substitute(strtrans(@a),'\^@',' ','g')
```

Or, I can simply use visual selection with `v` and grab the line without the return (this is much easier).

I can then use the global command to perform the replacement:

```
:g/old target line/s/.*/\=@a
```

Comment: One improvement is that I should use visual selection mode `v` and yank the line, hence removing the remove newlines from a register step.