# Putting "\n" in my .c or .cpp file using vim

Tags: vim

I'm using vim to make my programs in c/c++ and I would like to know how can I put "\n" (which represents a newline) in my code or use "%" using `:%s`.

For instance, sometimes I forget to put "%" in front of "d" or "f" in many lines or forget to put "\n" in some `printf()` calls.

```
printf("This is my d code.", x);
```

But the following command does not work, it puts a space in place of "\n"!

```
:%s/\<code.\>/code.\n/gc
```

or

```
:%s/\<d\>/%d/gc
```

How can I do what I want?

Comment: `:%s/\<code\.\>/&\\n/gc`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace a character for a newline in Vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323/how-to-replace-a-character-for-a-newline-in-vim)

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't think the OP wants a literal newline in the printf statement. I think he wants `printf("This is my %d code.\n", x);` After running the two substitutions. (c doesn't allow newlines in strings)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: It's not a duplicate. The question is about inserting the two-character sequence `\n`, not inserting a literal newline.

Answer (score 4):

The `:help s/\n` has the answer:

> ```
>   \n    insert a <NL> (<NUL> in the file)
>     (does NOT break the line)              *s/\n*
> ```

You'll also find the solution there: to **insert a literal backslash, escape it `\\` by doubling**; to **split the line, a `\r` has to be used**. Yes, this is inconsistent, and it works differently in similar tools like `sed`, but that's unfortunately how it is.

#### Notes

- The `\n` doesn't insert a space, but the special `<NL>` character, which usually is shown as `^@`.
- The `\<code.\>` isn't right; to match a literal period, you have to escape it: `\.`. Else, it matches *any character*. Likewise, the `.` usually isn't a *keyword character*, so the `\>` boundary wouldn't match.
- You don't need to repeat the match text in the replacement, you can use `&` for it. Also read up on *capture groups* (`:help /\(`) and the submatch references `:help s/\1`. This is a better way:

```
:%s/\<code\./&\\n/gc
```

(I don't see a problem with the second substitution.)

Comment: I don't think he wants a literal new line. I think he wants `printf("This is my %d code.\n", x);` After running the two substitutions. (c doesn't allow newlines in strings)

Comment: @FDinoff Ah, right. I've adapted my answer. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 3):

You want to insert the two-character sequence `\n`, not a literal newline (the latter would create a syntax error).

A sample line to be changed is:

```
printf("This is my d code.", x);
```

One problem with your attempt:

```
:%s/\<code.\>/code.\n/gc
```

is that there is no word boundary between the `.` and the `"` following the word `code`. The other problem is that `\` in the target is used to escape special characters (for example you can refer to a `/` character as `\/`), so the `\` must itself be escaped.

This should do the job:

```
:%s/\<code\."/code.\\n"/gc
```

A more general solution might be:

```
:g/printf/s/"/\\n"/egc
```

which offers to replace `"` by `\n"` on each line that contains `printf` -- but that will miss any `printf` calls that span more than one line.

As for replacing the `d` by `%d`, the command you have in your question:

```
:%s/\<d\>/%d/gc
```

is correct.