# file to string and string to file in bash

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell, command-line

I want to convert file to string and do some processing and get back same to file again in bash shell in Linux.

Mainly, aim is to remove new line `'\n'` by `';'` which is not exist in file and get file gain by replacing `';'` by `'\n'`.(; is non exists in file)

when I checked file with `:set list` to check all character in the file.
I can see `$` at end of line and when I run :

```
:%s/\n\;\g
```

to replace it works but next

```
:%s/;/\n\g
```

don't work, I can see character `^@` instead of `$` at the new line.

How can it be achieved in shell?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to read the content of a whole file, manipulate that end write out as new file? Better give some example; and include the full script you wrote so far.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are talking about vim command line.
I highly doubt when you said `:%s/\n\;\g` is working.

To replace newline with ';' try: `:%s/\n/;/g`

Similarly ';' to newline try `:%s/;/\r/g`

Clear explanation of why to use `\r` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71334/5436341).

The usage of `%s` is `:%s/<string_to_be_replaced>/<string_to_be_replaced_with>/g` .

Answer (score 1):

Are you really talking about the shell or about `vi`? If you do mean the shell, the easiest way is to use `tr` to transliterate individual characters:

Replace all newlines with semicolons:

```
tr '\n' ';' < inputFile > outputFile
```

Replace all semicolons with newlines:

```
tr ';' '\n' < inputFile > outputFile
```