# How to add custom classes to items in emmet.io list wraps?

Tags: html, vim, replace, emmet

Is something like the following possible?
Transform this

```
apples
bananas
pizza
burger
juice
water
```

To:

```
<tr>
    <li class="first">apples</li>
    <li>bananas</li>
</tr>
<tr>
    <li class="first">pizza</li>
    <li>burger</li>
</tr>
<tr>
    <li class="first">juice</li>
    <li>water</li>
</tr>
```

I tried this with emmet.io: `tr>td.first*1+td*2` but it didn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, I'd play with substitute (`:h :substitute` and groups+references in vim -> `:h /\(`, `:h /\1`), however, this one has been tricky because of the multilines issues.

```
:%s#\(\S*\)\n\(\S*\)\n#<tr>\r  <li class="first">\1</li>\r  <li>\2\</li>\r</tr>\r
```

Note:

- the use of `\n` in the regex part and of `\r` in the replacement part are not innocent. They are the only way to represent end-of-line in their respective parts when using Vim -- don't ask me why, though I remember a question on the subject on SO or was it on vi.SE.
- I have chosen `#` as delimiter instead of the usual `/` in order to simplify the replacement texts.

Comment: Yes, I read the question just today. It was on stackoverflow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323/how-to-replace-a-character-by-a-newline-in-vim#71334)

Comment: Is it also possible with multiple words in one line? Like `apples and bananas\npizza and burger\n
juice and water`. I couldn't figure out how this works.

Comment: What about `^.*$` as the pattern instead of `\S*`?