# ^M vs \n in vim string replacement

Tags: vim, replace, newline

There seems to be some sort of asymmetry in the way Vim treats `^M` when doing string replacement (`:s/x/y/`).

Perhaps an example is best; say we have this text file:

```
foo:bar:biz
```

I want to split this into lines. This works fine:

```
:s/:/^M/g
```

(note that `^M` is produced by typing `Ctrl-V`, `Enter`)

This results in the text file:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

Now, if I undo that and try again, I notice that this does *not* work:

```
:s/:/\n/g
```

Here, the resulting text is:

```
foo^@bar^@biz
```

That is to say, they are joined by the ASCII `NUL` byte (`0x00`).

**Question 1:** Why does using `\n` in the replacement result in `NUL` bytes?

Now, I figure "okay, I guess `^M` is used as the 'line separator' character in some way, for Vim; I can work with that".

So I do another experiment, starting with the one-item-per-line text file:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

and now, I want to join them with colons, so it looks like the very first incarnation, above.

So I run:

```
:%s/^M/:/
```

But this fails, with the error:

```
E486: Pattern not found: ^M
```

However, this command does work:

```
:%s/\n/:/
```

producing:

```
foo:bar:biz:
```

(I can get rid of the trailing colon myself)

So **Question 2**: Why does `\n` work in this case, where `^M` does not?

And ultimately, **Question 3**: Why is there this asymmetry between `\n` and `^M` depending on whether it's on the right- or left-hand side of a string replacement command?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/71323/5048383

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When searching, `\n` is a "catch-all" atom that conveniently matches any kind of "end-of-line": `CRLF`, `CR`, and `LF`.

When replacing, `\n` is `<Nul>` and represented as `^@`.

When replacing, `\r` is the legal "end-of-line" for the current `fileformat`.

In short, get used to this pattern and carry on:

```
:s/\n/\r
```

See `:help NL-used-for-Nul` and `CR-used-for-NL`.

Comment: Thanks for the help links. It looks like the fundamental issue is that the "search" and "replace" portions of `s///` use different syntax, and that's just the way it is. Other help pages for future searchers: `:help sub-replace-special`, `:help pattern`, `:help :s`.  For the replacement side, `\r` and `^M` have identical meaning (which the help page indicates with "idem", which I find slightly odd).