# How do you replace with a newline in VsCode Vim

Tags: regex, vim, newline, visual-studio-code

None of the suggestions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323/how-to-replace-a-character-by-a-newline-in-vim) work, nor does a search on issues in the [repo](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=newline) turn up anything.

I'd like to replace all `><` with `>\r\n<` inside a selection

```
'<,'>s/></?/g
```

what goes in place of the question mark?

Comment: I think there must be `\r`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323/how-to-replace-a-character-by-a-newline-in-vim

Comment: What is "VsCode Vim"?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried that, as I said in the question, I tried the suggestions listed in the same place your link, and mine in the question point to.

Comment: @romainl Visual Studio Code's Vim Extension, also, you can find that information by putting your mouse over the tag in the question, also by clicking the tag.

Comment: @Maslow, the tag only mention VS Code itself, not a "Vim Extension".

Comment: This appears broken. I opened a bug report https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/1575

Answer (score 3):

Does this work for you?

```
:'<,'>s/></>\r</g
```

Are you on windows and trying to insert both (literal) `\r` (carriage return) and `\n` (new line) ?

Comment: That will work in Vim but not in VsCode Vim. Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin I haven't, I was trying to figure out what the problem is from OPs question, I don't have access to Vscod myself.

Comment: as @ShaunLuttin said, that works in most vim implementations but not the VsCode version

Answer (score 2):

I just had success a moment ago moving asterisks to the start of a new line (i.e. replace asterisk chars with newline + asterisk) with:

```
:%s/\*/\r*/g
```

for clarity, that's:

```
:%s   (replace in whole file)
\*    (literal asterisk)
\r*   (new line followed by literal asterisk)
g     (operate on all matches on any given line)
```