# How to remove ^M special character in VI mode - Can't remove using dos2unix, can't print the whole line doing cat or grep

Tags: grep, echo, special-characters, vi, dos2unix

**Linux**: RHEL5 Tikanga 
**Version**: 2.6.18-402.el5 (per uname -a)

I'm creating a file by grepping some line from a windows source file (which contains some `Version=x.x.x` value) and putting it to new file `aa.txt`. This works fine for finding and grepping part.

Doing it something like `echo -n "AA "; echo "$(grep "Version=[1-9]" /some/mounted/loc/windows/sourcefile.txt) -" >> aa.txt`.

- I have to use `echo -n` for `AA` separately i.e. I can't club `echo AA`with `echo version part` with the latter echo command.

So, the resultant `aa.txt` file visually looks like this:
[image]
Now, if I `cat` it, it doesn't print the first line, just the last `-` character.

If I use `dos2unix` (which actually works for removing the line ending character only and converts a Windows format file to a Linux line ending character format file), it's still not working as `^M` in first line is not the last character in the line. **PS**: If you notice, the color of first `^M` is different than the second line one, which I added manually by typing.

Running `od -cab aa.txt` (octal dump) on this file, shows me that:

1. for first `^M`, the characters are `\r`,  `cr sp` and `015 040` (i.e. carriage return and an invisible space character).
2. for the second line, `^M`, is showing me normal values as `^ M`, `^ M` and `136 115` (as I manually typed `^` and `M` in the second line, this was expected).

**Question:**
1. Using `tr -d '\r' < aa.txt > new.aa.txt` I can solve this issue but what pattern I can use within `vi` or `vim` to remove this character in command mode.
Tried `:%s/^M//g` but it didn't catch the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You presumably used an actual caret followed by an M? The character there is actually a Ctrl-M, which you can get with Ctrl-V followed by Ctrl-M.

Comment: Yes, how to remove it while in a `vi` command mode. I thought there was a sequence of characters that you have to press for `vi` to catch it something like `ESCAPE+[[+M` or similar.

Comment: Yeah, as I said, the sequence is Ctrl-V Ctrl-M. Ctrl-V tells `vi` that the next character should be taken as-is instead of having it's normal function.

Answer (score 1):

Type

> :%s/\r/\r/g

This is saying:

`:%s` Find and Replace (substitute) in the entire file (%)
`\r` find carriage returns
`\r` and replace with newlines (or replace it with nothing by leaving this out the second \r)
`g` multiple times in the same lines

I know it sounds stupid, but on the find part, vim includes carriage returns under `\r` and in the replace section vim uses newlines.

**Alternatives** that may work for you if the above doesn't work:

- Type the following keys (whilst in normal mode) exactly as you see them
  <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `:e ++ff=dos`+ `:set ff=unix`

If you are working on a **Windows** machine the following may work:

- <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: That is not correct. For finding new lines you should use `\n`. `\r` is used for replacing.

Comment: how do you mean?

Comment: When you search for `\r` you won't find new lines, you will only find carriage returns, if there are some. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71334/5773806)

Comment: Ah I see the problem, I was using the terms "newline" and "carriage return" interchangeably. I'll edit my response now.